# Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long';

Tags: java, spring, exception, named-query

I make a method of search using named query

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM working_day w INNER JOIN \r\n"
            + "employees_days e ON \r\n"
            + "w.day_id = e.day_id\r\n"
            + "WHERE w.date LIKE %:date% AND e.employee_id LIKE %:employee_id%", nativeQuery = true)
    List<WorkingDay> searchDaysForMonth(@Param("date") String date, @Param("employee_id") Long employeeId);
```

Service:

```
public List<WorkingDay> countDays(String date, Long employeeId) {
    return workingDayRepository.searchDaysForMonth(date, employeeId);
}
```

Controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/employees")

@GetMapping(value = "/employees/days_in_month")
    public ModelAndView getDaysForEmployee(@RequestParam(value = "date", required = false) String date,
                                           @RequestParam(value = "employee_id") Long employeeId) {

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("days_employees");

        var daysForEmployee = employeeService.countDays(date, employeeId);
        modelAndView.addObject("days_employees", daysForEmployee);

        Employee employee = employeeService.getById(employeeId);
        modelAndView.addObject("employee", employee);

        var totalDays = daysForEmployee.size();
        modelAndView.addObject("totalDays", totalDays);

        return modelAndView;
    }
```

When I enter the following mapping value

`http://localhost:8080/employees/days_in_month?date=2023-01&employee_id=2`

I get `MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException. Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long';`

How to solve this?

Comment: It looks like your `employee_id` is an integer value - what are you hoping that a `LIKE` filter will achieve?

Comment: Where are you calling `searchDaysForMonth`? You are not showing the call of that method. Or is the exception already thrown in/before the controller method?

Comment: Just use `AND e.employee_id = :employee_id`

Comment: After I corrected my query it still doesn't work.  @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM working_day w INNER JOIN \r\n"
   + "employees_days e ON \r\n"
   + "w.day_id = e.day_id\r\n"
   + "WHERE w.date LIKE %:date% AND e.employee_id = %:employee_id%", nativeQuery = true)

Comment: `"...e.employee_id = %:employee_id%"` doesn't seem corrected. Do you realize that the `%...%` syntax is for the `like` operator? Why don't you use what Tim suggested: `" ... e.employee_id = :employee_id"`?

Comment: e.employee_id = :employee_id doesn't work too